# Data binding issue in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am working on an execise app.  My app adopts MVVM. I am trying to create a window with two user controls, one of user control includes a datagrid which gets its data from viewmodel.
I expect the datagrid gets auto-filled with my default values (private fileds) when the app runs.  But there is binding error:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=windowView'. BindingExpression:Path=ActivePacket; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='dataGrid1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Thanks!

Here is my code:

========= MainWindow.xaml ================

```
    <Window x:Class="Project.Abc.Try.MainWindow"
        x:Name="windowView"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Abc.Try"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:PayloadViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="78*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="233*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:CmdMenuView Grid.Row="0" Margin="6,6,3,6" />
        <local:PayloadView Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,6,3,6" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

============ PayloadView.xaml ===========

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Project.Abc.Try.PayloadView"
             x:Name="PLview"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="199" d:DesignWidth="588" >

    <Grid Height="200" Width="580" >
        <!--<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,20,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=ActivePacket}"> -->
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,20,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=windowView, Path=ActivePacket}">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PacketId, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="PacketID " Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PacketLength, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="PacketLength" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Spare}" Header="Byte 6" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Send" Command="{Binding Path=SendCommand}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,122,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

=================== PayloadViewModel.cs  ========================

```
namespace Project.Abc.Try
{
    public class PayloadViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // ......
        private CmdPacket _activePacket;
        public CmdPacket ActivePacket
        {
            get { return _activePacket; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _activePacket)
                {
                    _activePacket = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActivePacket");
                }
            }
        }
        // .........
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign the `DataContext` to your view in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<local:PayloadView ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext}" />
```

And in `PayloadView.xaml`, just bind to the view model property:

```
<DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding ActivePacket}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified my code according to your suggestion. The binding error message has gone, but I still don't see any data showing up in DataGrid on UI. Debug-Output windows always has "System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=ActivePacket; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='dataGrid1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
".  What's the problem?

Comment: @KaiMon Is `CmdPacket` a `Collection` type? Is it initialized? Please read more about `DataGrid.ItemsSource` on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx to help you sort this out.

Comment: Thank you.  I found out that the program did not create an CmdPacket Object because its contructor was not setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts...
If you don't need anything from the PayloadViewModel anywhere except your PayloadView, you could bind the PayloadViewModel directly in the DataContext of your your PayloadView, and then just bind right to it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Abc.Try.PayloadView" ...>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:PayloadViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    ...

    <DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding ActivePacket}" />

    ...

</UserControl>
```

Also, if you are wanting to do MVVM, you may want to consider using Caliburn.Micro if you haven't. It automatically binds each View's datacontext to its corresponding ViewModel with no code (i.e. PayloadView would automatically have access to public properties on PayloadViewModel). Then all you would have to write is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Abc.Try.PayloadView" ...>

    ...

    <DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding ActivePacket}" />

    ...

</UserControl>
```

Here is a great tutorial for Caliburn.Micro: http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/

Hope this helps.